Did the Earth shake and the sun darken on the day of the supposed Ichadon Buddhist miracle?
According to the Wikipedia article on Miracles, section Buddhism:

The Haedong Kosung-jon of Korea (Biographies of High Monks) records that King Beopheung of Silla had desired to promulgate Buddhism as the state religion. However, officials in his court opposed him. In the fourteenth year of his reign, Beopheung's "Grand Secretary", Ichadon, devised a strategy to overcome court opposition. Ichadon schemed with the king, convincing him to make a proclamation granting Buddhism official state sanction using the royal seal. Ichadon told the king to deny having made such a proclamation when the opposing officials received it and demanded an explanation. Instead, Ichadon would confess and accept the punishment of execution, for what would quickly be seen as a forgery. Ichadon prophesied to the king that at his execution a wonderful miracle would convince the opposing court faction of Buddhism's power. Ichadon's scheme went as planned, and the opposing officials took the bait. According to legend when Ichadon was executed on the 15th day of the 9th month in 527, his prophecy was fulfilled; the earth shook, the sun was darkened, beautiful flowers rained from the sky, his severed head flew to the sacred Geumgang mountains, and milk instead of blood sprayed 100 feet in the air from his beheaded corpse. The omen was accepted by the opposing court officials as a manifestation of heaven's approval, and Buddhism was made the state religion in 527 CE.

I am limiting this to only those two occurrences from the supposed miracle because they should in theory be verifiable from our science. So we know that:

On the 15th day of the 9th month in 527 CE, the Earth shook in Korea
On the 15th day of the 9th month in 527 CE, the sun darkened in Korea

Did these two events happen on that day?

Scientifically, we can't yet detect evidence of earthquakes on specific days more than 1000 years ago.

@Avery I didn't know that. Well, what about the sun darkening?

Eclipses can certainly be predicted. The only way to confirm bad weather would be other Korean sources from that time, which I'm not aware of

Solar eclipses in 527 occurred on March 18 and September 11.  However, neither of them was visible from Korea.  https://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/5MCSEmap/0501-0600/527-09-11.gif

The Haedong Goseungjeon wasn't compiled until 7 centuries after that event, so inaccuracies may have crept into the tale during that time.

"milk instead of blood sprayed 100 feet in the air from his beheaded corpse" If there isn't already a violent martial arts movie featuring this scene, there should be.

Leaving aside that "a wonderful miracle" isn't much of a prediction...
There was no eclipse visible in Gyeongju that year
"The sun was darkened" could mean a lot of things. Storm clouds or smoke cover the Sun, for example. But let's check the most obvious and dramatic: an eclipse.
Using NASA's Javascript Solar Eclipse Explorer, and entering the coordinates for Gyeongju the capital of Silia, there was a partial eclipse on 523-11-23 and the next was on 529-01-26.

I can find no record of an earthquake in that year
Historical earthquake data of Korean (see the Appendix on page 13) does not list an earthquake in 527. As this was felt at court, one would expect it to have been recorded.


+1 Awesome work and thank you so much for the comprehensive and sourced answer!
